# PM2 environmental variables with vue

Tags: vue.js, pm2

I have a web application using vue, built with vue-cli for the front end and wanting to switch to use PM2s static page serve. Everything is working fine but noticed PM2 can also declare the environmental variables for the vue app via the ecosystem.config.js file. Trying to set those in that file, I am not able to get it to work. Specifically, its my vue app api url. It works fine if I keep my .env file in the directory with the same var defined but once I remove that, kill PM2 and restart the app, the app does not work leading me to believe the env variables set in the ecosystem.config.js file is not working.

This is what I currently have in my ecosystem.config.js file -

```js
module.exports = {
    "apps" : [{
        "name": "AppName",
        "script": "serve",
        "exec_mode": "cluster",
        "instances" : 2,
        "env_develop": {
            "PM2_SERVE_PATH": 'dist',
            "PM2_SERVE_PORT": 8084,
            "PM2_SERVE_SPA": 'true',
            "PM2_SERVE_HOMEPAGE": '/index.html',
            "NODE_ENV": 'develop',
            "VUE_APP_API_URL": "http://myappurl.com/api/",
          }
    }],

    "deploy" : {
        "develop" : {
          "user" : "username",
          "key"  : "/home/user/.ssh/key.priv",
          "host" : "localhost",
          "ref"  : "origin/develop",
          "repo" : "gitrepourl",
          "path" : "/home/user/FE",
          "pre-deploy-local": "",
          "post-deploy" : "npm ci && npm run build && pm2 startOrReload ecosystem.config.js --env develop",
          "pre-setup": ""
        }
      }
}
```

Any insight on what I may be doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: In order to pass env vars to frontend app, it should be built with them, while you're running already built app from dist, I guess

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am rebuilding the app when I try removing my .env file and using the ecosystem.config.js file.